# How to wait until state in useContext is completely loaded?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, mern, react-context, use-context

I want to populate the input field initially with the fullname value available in "state". But I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of null` error when I reload the page, since the state is not yet loaded at that time.

```
function EditProfile(){
    const {state,dispatch}= useContext(UserContext); //line 1

    const [fullname, setFullname]= useState(state.fullname); //line 2


    return(
           <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={fullname}></input>

       )
}
```

I tried changing the line 2 like this:

```
const [fullname, setFullname]= useState(state?state.fullname:"");
```

This time I didn't get any errors. But the input field contains empty string instead of `state.fullname` value.

I want the state to be loaded completely (line 1) before defining the useState for fullname (line 2).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `useEffect` to update the state when context data is fetched

```
function EditProfile(){
    const {state,dispatch}= useContext(UserContext); //line 1
  
    const [fullname, setFullname]= useState(state?.fullname); //line 2

    useEffect(() => {
        setFullname(state?.fullname);
    }, [state?.fullname]);
    return(
           <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={fullname}></input>

       )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sharing reactive data through context there is no need to create another local state because it's already reactive. Besides, updating data on the consumer component causes the data state to be out of sync between the consumer and provider components. If you need to update the provider state in the consumer component, you can just share a function through the context for mutating the state.

Anyway if you need to create a local state based on context data, the best way is to use a `useEffect` as [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68677066/9481288) explained.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setFullname(state?.fullname)
}, [state])
```